# Does observing 100 firebase paths in parallel can be non efficient?

Tags: ios, firebase

I have this data structure:

```
{
 userId: {
         userId:

                {

                 messageId:

                 (...)

                }

          (...)

        }

(...)

}
```

For a given top level `userId` I would like to observe all its `userId` child. 
There could be 100 child path to be observed.

Does observing 100 firebase paths in parallel can be non efficient?

**EDIT:**

New Data Structure with proper indexing:

```
/messages indexed on chatIds

{
chatId: (chatId of the chat it belongs to)
fromUserId:
...
}

/chat indexed on userIds

{
userId1: (users of the chat whose id are ordered alphabetically)

userId2:

...
}
```

**Workflow :**

the app get current userId -> get the list of chat index on userId -> get messages corresponding to the chat which are indexed on chatId

Comment: Inefficient in what sense? Bandwidth usage? Time it takes to retrieve the data? Amount of code? Code complexity? And how do you intend to listen to all paths? Also: what is the alternative you have in mind. It's a lot easier for us to answer "which approach is more efficient: A or B?" than "might this be inefficient?".

Comment: I was asking about code complexity. On iOS when the app become active I listen to all sender's userId (2nd level userId) of the current user (top level userID). It allows the app to observe every message that is sent to the user. This data structure allows to get data much quicker thanks to a more precise path.

Does listenning to a lot of paths can slow down the iOS device?

Comment: I have edited my question with a possible solution. However is retrieving hundreds of rows among possibly billions of rows efficient if indexing on a child key?

Comment: Querying from an index is orders-of-magnitude more efficient than looping through all items. But nothing beats direct-access, i.e. `ref.child('messages-for-user').child(auth.uid)`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What about observing a lot of paths on the device: would it cost a lot of CPU or memory?

Comment: I would suggest that if the app has to observe a lot of paths, you can probably group your data to where you can observe one path for the changes. In the New Data Structure shown above, observing add/edit/remove events in the messages node will notify your app of any changes to that node: specifically which message changed, the chat id, the userid etc. There would be no need to observe any other nodes within that node. That node could have billions and billions of children. and your app would only be working with one changed child at a time.

Answer (score 0):

In the example provided there's a userId: node inside a userId: node. That needs to be re-worked.

While monitoring 100 nodes is doable, it sounds like there may be a way to flatten your data to reduce that.

By the example code provided, it appears you are interested in changes to the messages node for each user. Perhaps you are coding an app that involves messaging between users?

One option would be to break out the messages node so then there would be a Users node and a Messages node as such:

```
Users:
  uid_0:
    user 0 data
  uid_1:
    user 1 data
  uid_2:
    user 2 data

Messages:
  msg_0:
     "posted_by_uid": "uid_0"
     "msg": "some message that uid_0 posted"
  msg_1:
     "posted_by_uid": "uid_1"
     "msg": "some message that uid_1 posted"
```

Then observing the messages node for changes enables you to just get the data you need - the uid of the user that posted the message and the message itself. There's a 100 different ways to structure the data but the idea is to monitor the node that has the data you are interested in.

Messages will change frequently but a Users node that stores their favorite food within their uid is pretty static so while you can also keep an eye on the Users node for changes, you are now just observing 2 nodes instead of 100 or 1000.

Comment: Thank you for your answer with a denormalized datastructure.

It has led to a new edit of my question with a possible answer with a chat object which enables to link user and messages.